# Can't post any data in MVC 6 Web Api application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an Web Api application with simple controller. Get methods work fine, but i have an issue with post and put requests.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
public class LessonController : Controller {
    ...
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody] Lesson lesson) {
        ...
    }
    ....
}
```

where `Lesson` is

```
public class Lesson {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsModerated { get; set; }
    public int? PrevLessonId { get; set; }
    public int? NextLessonId { get; set; }
}
```

So i try to send request and have no luck, lesson is just an object with default-initialized properties. I sent request in two way: first with js

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:1822/api/lesson/1',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        lesson: {
        description: "Fourth lesson description",
        isModerated: true,
        name: "Fourth lesson",
        nextLessonId: 5,
        prevLessonId: 3,
        text: "Fourth lesson text"
    }}),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

and with Postman: [image: Postman screen]

So the content type is correct. Can anyone tell me what problem is connected with?

**UPD:**
I have tried to use `PostLesson` model, that contains all properties from `Lesson` but `Id` and sent request via Postman with UpperCamelCase data in body, but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Your Lesson object has an Id. In order for model binding to occur, the objects need to match exactly; that also goes for the capitalization of the properties.

Comment: No, it is not a fix for my problem, I have created a new class `PostLesson` with all field from `Lesson` but `Id` and it does not solve my problem.

Comment: The new class you created is camelCase with the property names having the first letter lowercase like the body content you're posting?

Comment: No, new class is UpperCamelCase, but i have sent data in request with UpperCase naming style too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my own issue. In fact the problem is pretty simple.
We just need to pass object in `Post` method that equals of structure of `Lesson` model without specify argument name. So my js code need looks like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:1822/api/lesson/1',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        description: "Fourth lesson description",
        isModerated: true,
        name: "Fourth lesson",
        nextLessonId: 5,
        prevLessonId: 3,
        text: "Fourth lesson text"
    }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

For some addition information see [this link](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/).